# JS runtime error: Object expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have been adding a menu bar to my page which contains 2 pages of JS which have correctly been linked to the page and 1 CSS file which has also been correctly linked. I have already put this bar on 4 other pages and it worked fine and no errors. The only thing different about this page is it has ajax toolkit on it.

Here is the code where the error is coming from:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>

<div class="Wrapper">
    <div class="bsimplex-header-bar">
        <ul class="modern-menu theme2">
            <li><a href="../Common/bWelcomePage.aspx"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="Manager/bManagerPage.aspx"><span>Manager</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Absences</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Absences/bSicknessPage.aspx"><span>Sickness</span</a>
</li>
                   <li><a href="Absences/bMedicalPage.aspx"><span>Medical</span></a>      </li>
                    <li><a href="Absences/bLatenessPage.aspx"><span>Lateness</span></a>   </li>
                    <li><a href="Absences/bOtherPage.aspx"><span>Other</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Reports</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Allocation</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Rota</span></a>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Admin/bAdminPage.aspx"><span>Admin</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="bPersonnelDashboardPage.aspx"><span style="background-color: #f08100 !important;">My Calender</span></a></li>

            <ul class="mm-group mm-right">
                <li class="mm-icon">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="mm-container">
                                <span class="mm-over mm-dashboard"></span>
                                <span class="mm-dashboard"></span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">$(".modern-menu").modernMenu();</script>
    </div>
</div> <!-- closing div missing? -->
```

The Error comes from the Bottom script tag, saying `Object expected`.

Here is where I have used the AJAX toolkit before the code.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

I have also used it in my earlier bit of code?

Does anyone know what the issue is?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Javascript/bSimplexMenuBarTransit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Javascript/bSimplexMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Javascript/MenuBarAdmin/AdminMenuJS.js"></script>
<script src="../../Javascript/MenuBarAdmin/AdminMenuJSmin.js"></script>
<link href="../../Stylesheet/bPersonnelTracker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../Stylesheet/ScheduleStyle/bsimplex.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../Stylesheet/bSimplexVericalBar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../Stylesheet/bSimplexMenuBar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: have you loaded jQuery?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, Its with my links i will edit my post now to show that.

Comment: @user3129331 What is `modern-menu` ? I cannot find a class with this name

Comment: @Dot_NETJunior 4th line down.

Comment: try it but not sure, <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">$('.modern-menu').modernMenu();</script>

Comment: @sany2k8 Says that Language is not an attribute of script.

Comment: try with single quotes <script type='text/javascript'>$(".modern-menu theme2").modernMenu();</script>

Comment: @sany2k8 Nope, it wont be the line of code that is wrong as it works for the other pages i think its the AJAX.

Comment: I added a missing end div </div> (see edited code above) that is either a typo or could be your problem.

Comment: @rontornambe Thats just because there is more code on the page i didnt paste in haha :)

Comment: Kinda though so, but some errors are that simple.